# AlarmManager + Service on Idle (screen off)

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I call my Service with alarm manager

like this:

```
 alarmManage.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + getPoolingInterval(), pendingIntentPolling);
```

On my **ServicePooling** i reschedule it of the same way, and this **ServicePooling** call another service to send data on my service.

```
Intent serviceSocket = new Intent(this.context, SenderService.class);
    this.context.startService(serviceSocket);
```

All works very well every minut i receive on my server a polling communication, but when my device are screen off and without USB plugged, this stop work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea to use `Service` for `AlarmManager` nowadays. Use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead. your device fall asleep then unplugged.

```
public class BRMine extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String INTENT_FILTER = "com.example.BRMine";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        OWakeLocker.acquire(ctx, _.indexNOTS);
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(ctx.getPackageName(),
                SMine.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(ctx, intent.setComponent(comp));
    }

}
```

where:

public class OWakeLocker {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock[] wakeLocks = new PowerManager.WakeLock[_.indexNOTS_MAX];//Services count

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void acquire(Context ctx, int index) {
    WakeLock wakeLock = wakeLocks[index];
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, _.APPNAME + Integer.toString(index));
    if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()){
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
}

public static void release(int index) {
    WakeLock wakeLock = wakeLocks[index];
    if (wakeLock != null) 
        wakeLock.release();
        wakeLock = null;
}}
```

to start:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(BRMine.INTENT_FILTER);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, myintentalarm, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT):
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
```

Comment: i ll make a try with this WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: same problem, i think the problem is on setExact when device is on idle state.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem using a answer of Vyacheslav but wihtout AlarmManager because setExact didint work for me on idle and my android is a api lower then 23 (and don't have setExactAndAllowWhileIdle) i use a timertask on startapplication in my case works werry well, i just need this when my application are runnning.